# Quickblox iOS - Error Creating User in New SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I've upgraded to QuickBlox SDK V 2.4.3. Now, when trying to create a user using the following code:

```
QBUUser *user = [QBUUser new];
user.password = self.userPassword.text;
user.login = self.userDisplayName.text;

[QBRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
    //
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    //
}];
```

I'm getting this error:

```
+[QBRequest signUp:successBlock:errorBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10db84
```

Comment: I am assuming the app crashes right when it gets to the line creating the block for signup request?

Comment: @NSNoob yes, that's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else that has this problem, I solved it by adding -ObjC in 'Other Linker Flags' in your target's Build Settings.

Comment: I've already have -ObjC added, but I'm getting a 'Token required..' error. Do you know what's that about?

Comment: @Septronic if you're using the older version of the Quickblox SDK you have to create the session manually.

Comment: I'm using the latest one, and I don't know how to create a session, I followed the tutorials by quickblox, yet to no avail! I don't suppose you'd know how to do it?

Comment: @Septronic in the newest SDK you don't need to manually create sessions, just setup you app keys in the appdelegate      [QBApplication sharedApplication].applicationId = your_app_id;;
    [QBConnection registerServiceKey:@"your_app_service_key"];;
    [QBSettings setAuthorizationSecret:@"your_app_authorization_secret"];;

Comment: Thanks for the instruction, but that's very strange because I've already done those, and I'm still getting the token error.